# How to use the settings of quantity_total to extract the number of time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How does `quantity_total` parameter returns the total quantity of the time series in Apache IoTDB? Currently the settings I use is `cluster-"defaultCluster",nodelype-"DATANoDE",nodeld="1",name-"pointsIn", database-"root.poit prod", region="8")`, and I currently can only extract the number of data written. I want to know how should I write the command to sum the number of time series?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command in Apache IoTDB: `sum(schema_region{cluster=~"$cluster", nodeType=~"$nodeType", instance=~"$instance", name!="schema_region_mem_usage"}) by (name)`.